# Flexbox grow inside anchor

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I'm facing a problem where I would like an anchor flexbox child to take all remaining height available. I thought that adding `flex-grow: 1` would suffice but it is not working. The div inside the anchor does not take the full height.

**Question**: Is there a way to make it work without converting my plain anchor to a flexbox element?

Here is a codepen illustrating the issue: 
https://codepen.io/alansouzati/pen/YVpYeO

[image]

I've created 3 tiles where the first one has the anchor to exemplify. You can see that the price does not align with the other siblings.

Comment: Why do you not want to make your wrapping `a` tag a `flex` container?

Comment: Because I would like to have the children drive that behavior. I just don't want to assume that the child of a plain anchor will always be a flexbox container.

Comment: Another reason is: if the plain anchor has a `display: flex` I would need to decide the flex direction inside the anchor itself, which seems odd to me. The child should decide whether direction should be row or column, right? Hopefully if makes sense

Comment: Nothing wrong with making an anchor element a flex container. On the contrary, it can lead to simpler and cleaner HTML. Here's an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmNQRy?editors=1100

Comment: @AlanSouza That children of a flex container should know if to flow in a row or a column without setting their direction, makes no more sense than a block element with a fixed height should know when to scroll and when to hidden/clip the content. What make sense is if a given property to a parent element has more than one possible behavior, you should tell the children which one, so you control what's gonna happen, not the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.plain` is not a flex parent, so setting `flex-grow: 1` on `.service` doesn't do anything.

Just add `display: flex` to `.plain`

```css
.tiles {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  padding: 12px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tile {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  background-color:  white;
  margin: 12px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tile:hover {
  background-color:  #f1f1f1;
}

.service {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 12px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.service-body {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

p {
  color: #a8a8a8;
}

.plain {
  margin: 0;
  color:inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class='tiles'>
  <div class='tile'>
    <a href="http://google.com" class='plain' target="_blank">
      <div class='service'>
        <h2>Service 1</h2>
        <div class='service-body'>
          <p>This is a sample service</p>
        </div>
        <span>$9.99</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='tile'>
    <div class='service'>
      <h2>Service 2</h2>
      <div class='service-body'>
        <p>This is a sample service</p>
      </div>
      <span>$9.99</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='tile'>
    <div class='service'>
      <h2>Service 3</h2>
      <div class='service-body'>
        <p>This is a sample service with a long text that will make things render differently</p>
      </div>
      <span>$9.99</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks michael and the community. After reading more about flexbox I get that I should be using display: flex.

Answer (score 2):

See Below. I made the ".service" after the anchor tag absolute and relative to the main container. Hope it helps

```css
.tiles {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  padding: 12px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tile {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  background-color:  white;
  margin: 12px;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;/**Added Code**/
}

.tile:hover {
  background-color:  #f1f1f1;
}

.service {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 12px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.service-body {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

p {
  color: #a8a8a8;
}

.plain {
  margin: 0;
  color:inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
/**Added Code**/
.plain > .service {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='tiles'>
  <div class='tile'>
    <a href="http://google.com" class='plain' target="_blank">
      <div class='service'>
        <h2>Service 1</h2>
        <div class='service-body'>
          <p>This is a sample service</p>
        </div>
        <span>$9.99</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='tile'>
    <div class='service'>
      <h2>Service 2</h2>
      <div class='service-body'>
        <p>This is a sample service</p>
      </div>
      <span>$9.99</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='tile'>
    <div class='service'>
      <h2>Service 3</h2>
      <div class='service-body'>
        <p>This is a sample service with a long text that will make things render differently</p>
      </div>
      <span>$9.99</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It definitely solves the problem. Although after reading all the comments and studying more about flexbox, I believe it makes more sense to make the plain anchor a display flex element. Because of that I will accept the answer from Michael. I appreciate your help.